# Add Multiselect dropdown in Odoo module

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I want to add a multiselect dropdown in Odoo module 
Field name will be Weekly Holiday which will be use to select multiple days of week

Below python is code i tried.
'weeklyholiday': fields.selection([('Sunday', 'Sunday'), ('Monday', 'Monday'), ('Tuesday', 'Tuesday'),('Wednesday', 'Wednesday'),], "Weekly Holiday"),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you can't have multiselection, unless you use some external field type. I suggest you instead to change your field in a many2many:

```
weeklyholiday = fields.Many2many('weekday')
```

with the following declaration in the view, you should be able to accomplish your need.

```
<field name="weeklyholiday" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_create_edit':'1'}"/>
```

Comment: what is 'weekday' here ? do i have to create new table?

Comment: yes, instead of a selection you need a simple model with code and description preloaded. You can use *hr_schedule_weekday* directly or copy it...